# can any one tell me regular expression for this? UPDATED

Tags: regex

I tried many syntax in vistal studio, and in [this site](http://regexlib.com/), but nothing helped.
The expression would be `_ct_(anyDigitHere)_`
like

```
 adkasjflasdjfsdf asdfkl sjfdsf _ct150_ asdfasd // so it would match this _ct150

any thing here doens't matter Random stuff..afd a&r9qwr89 ((
_ct415487_ anything here doesn't matter // this will match _ct415487_
```

basically any `_ctAndAnyNumberHere_` (underscore at start and end)
A couple I tried `^*(_ct)(:z)(+_)+*$`, `^*(_ct[0-9]+_)+*$`. But none helps!

**EDIT**
Thanks for the reply(ies). That did work, but what I now the problem is replace those matched elements with a hidden field value.. say..

if the value in hidden field is of `1` digit, (any value from 0-9), I have to take `last` digit from that matched expression and replace it with the value in hidden field.

if the value in hidden field is of `2` digit, (any value from 0-99), I have to take `last two` digits from that matched expression and replace it with the value in hidden field.

so, basically..

*if the value in hidden field is of `n` digit,  I have to take `last n` digits from that matched expression and replace it with the value in hidden field.*

How do I do that?

Comment: Like this: `^.*(_ct[0-9]+_).*$`? If so, you're just missing the dots. This will match the whole input and capture the `_ctXXX_` part. Matching just the `_ctXXX_` part is as in answers below.

Comment: @EugeneRyabtsev: yeah, I kinda figured it out just after I posted the question. But I need something else though, I have updated the question to reflect the change..

Comment: Seems too late, but I updated the question before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what language of visual studio you're talking about, but this should work:

```
_ct\d+_
```

or this:

```
_ct([0-9]+)_
```

**EDIT:**

```
Regex rg = new Regex("_ct([0-9]+)_");
string text = "any thing here doens't matter Random stuff..afd a&r9qwr89 ((_ct415487_ anything here doesn't matter";
var match = rg.Match(text).Groups[1].Value;
int sizeHiddenField = HiddenField1.Value.Length;

var newString = text.Replace(match, match.Substring(0, match.Length - sizeHiddenField) + HiddenField1.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks! That did worked, but I need something else too, I updated the question can you please see if you can help?

Answer (score 0):

```
/_ct\d*_/
```

This is the regular expression syntax for your given problem. Try this